# Swift , hide/remove a window (View?)

Tags: swift, firebase, uiview, connection, window

**I would like to remove the view I created on the code below (the window keyWindow or the v UIView).**

I tried with the .tag which works for view, but it's not working.

To explain the purpose of the code, it tests with Firebase if there is internet connection; if not, a no wifi gif appears in the middle of the screen ; if yes ,the no wifi gif should dissapear (but not in my case).

Here, it shows correctly the gif with the window (v) and when it get connectivity it tries the test to remove the view but it does nothing

This code should work on every uiviewcontroller of my app (that's my aim),but for now I'm testing it with a local func on a viewcontroller

**EDIT: here is the fixed code for who is interested :)**

```
 func testconnection() {



        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2), execute: {
            let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
            connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                if let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected {
                    print("Connected")
                    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
                    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x-50, y: self.view.center.y-10, width: 100, height: 100))
                    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                    v.tag = 100
                    print("Start testing to remove the view with correct tag")
                    if let viewWithTag = window.viewWithTag(100) {
                        print("yes, remove view")
                        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
                    }else{
                        print("Not the correct tag / view not created")
                    }



                }
                else {

                    print ("Not connected")


                    SDWebImageCodersManager.sharedInstance().addCoder(SDWebImageGIFCoder.shared())
                    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
                    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.center.x-50, y: self.view.center.y-10, width: 100, height: 100))
                    window.addSubview(v);
                    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "noWifi1", withExtension: "gif")!)
                    let advTimeGif = UIImage.gifImageWithData(imageData!)
                    let imageView2 = UIImageView(image: advTimeGif)
                    imageView2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
                    imageView2.tag = 100
                    v.addSubview(imageView2)




                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you add `v` to `window`, not `self.view`; as as result of that, `viewWithTag` is `nil`. To fix that, change `self.view.viewWithTag(100)` to `window.viewWithTag(100)`.

`viewWithTag(_:)` will look at the receiver's view hierarchy for a view with matching tag. In your case, `v` is not in `self.view`'s hierarchy.